# Regex.Split on "non-quoted whitespace" returning duplicate strings

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regex string that splits **single line** of string, with
*Command line argument style*. Where:

1. Whitespace (`\s+`)
2. Not Quoted by `"`

   2-a. ignore escaped `"` (ignore `\"`)

According to [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/4b26t) and [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/sqjZ0J/3)(link to test code), where I created this string, this had no problem as I understand.

Given the code:

```
Regex.Split("lorem \"ipsum door?!\" sit?! amet!!!", @"(?<=^(\\""|[^""])*((?<!\\)""(\\""|[^""])*((?<!\\)""))*(\\""|[^""])*)\s+")
//(?<=^(\\"|[^"])*((?<!\\)"(\\"|[^"])*((?<!\\)"))*(\\"|[^"])*)\s+
```

Expected:

```
lorem
"ipsum door?!"
sit?!
amet!!!
```

Returns:

```
lorem
l
"ipsum door?!"
l
"ipsum door?!"
i
"
sit?!
l
"ipsum door?!"
i
"

amet!!!
```

More info: Before adding condition 2-a(ignore `\"`), I came up with this and had a similar issue. Code/result: https://pastebin.com/76eKp1wb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get wanted result with option [RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options?view=netframework-4.7.2#explicit-captures-only)

Like so:

```
Regex splitter = new Regex(@"(?<=^(\\""|[^""])*((?<!\\)""(\\""|[^""])*((?<!\\)""))*(\\""|[^""])*)\s+", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
var lineBreak = splitter.Split("lorem \\\"ipsum \\\" door?!\" sit?! \" amet!!!");
```

Apparently, when **capturing** without or with any options, there is no difference. In other words, only when splitting, there is a problem.

My best guess is library trying to capture something in the capture group, and trying to split there.

Comment: Half RTFM, Half regex problem, I guess :)

Comment: You read the _wrong_ manual to truly understand the nature of your problem and its solution, though. [The `Regex.Split` manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) specifically states that **"If capturing parentheses are used in a Regex.Split expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array."**